# Can't play video on TV using cast-android-sample-master project

Tags: android, video, google-cast, chromecast

I'm developing playing video on TV via ChromeCast device.
I whitelisted my device and got APP ID from google.
I replaced it in receiver.html file and res/values/strings.xml file in Android project.
I ran the project, it found the chromecast. But can't play video on TV.
Nothing happens on TV.

I already uploaded receiver.html file into URL server that I registered when whitelisting.
Here my APP_ID: `<redacted>` 
Should I change it to `e81e1b35&#8211;414d&#8211;4684&#8211;82a0&#8211;c762837a2101`?
And put it to strings.xml file in Android project and receiver.html file.

Can anyone solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huy, first, it is best if you don't share your app id with the world :-) regarding your issue, putting "-" in the app id in your strings.xml is fine. First need to make sure your device is whitelisted; can you access your chromecast device through your chrome browser by hitting

`http://<ip-address-of-chromecast>:9222`

If not then there is an issue with your whitelising; in that case, did you remember to check the box 'Send serial number to Google' when you were setting up your chromecast device?

Comment: I can't access my chromecast device through my chrome browser in my phone via http://<ip-address-of-chromecast>:9222. When setting up chromecast device, I don't see "Send serial number to Google" checkbox.Just rename chromecast device and join network. But I access the Chromecast Setting and check "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates" checkbox. Then I reboot my chromecast device. But It doesn't work.

Comment: I just check the box "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates". Do I have to whitelist my chromecast device again to develop my app?

Comment: You don't need to, just give it a couple of hours and reboot and hopefully the whitelisting will work. If issue still persists then, contact us on the chromecast-updates mailing list.

Comment: I can play video now. Thanks a lot